# Get CSS_SELECTOR or XPATH of a Button Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, element

Hello I'm trying to click on a button but it's not working for me what I have tried so far is as follows:

[image]

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("id__1115").click()
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ms-Button.ms-Button--default.manageOwnersButtonStyle-1007').click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]/span[1]/span[1]/span[1]").click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

elements and click throwing error instead  element and click  because elements produce list and list is not clickable in selenium.

I changed my code to :

```
driver.find_element_
```

Only this xpath worked:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]/span[1]/span[1]/span[1]").click()
```

thanks

I don't how many elements. For example: (using xpath is better)

```
el = driver.find_elements_by_id("id__1115")
el[2].click()
```

Comment: If others selection produce more than  one then you can iterate or slicing then click

Answer (score 1):

If `Add owners` text is not gonna change then

You can use the below xpath

```
//span[text()='Add owners']/ancestor::button
```

Click on it like

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Add owners']/ancestor::button").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add owners']/ancestor::button"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.